# Can I decompose a tensor in this way?

Tags: tensors, svd, tensor-decomposition

I found several "generalizations" of the singular value decomposition (with some overlap), here is a short list to some references: [Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition), [Tensor Train](https://www.arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5713.pdf), [Tensor Train rank-1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1593), [CANDECOMP/PARAFAC (CP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition), [Tensor rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition), [Kruskal](http://people.ece.umn.edu/~nikos/SteSidLAAreprint.pdf).

None of these helped me find the following: given a tensor $G_{abcd}$ of shape $(r,s,t,t)$, I'd like to find a decomposition in the following form:

$$
G = \sum_i \sigma_i\, w_iz_i^\dagger\otimes T_i
$$

where $\mathrm{tr}(w_i^\dagger w_j)=\mathrm{tr}(z_i^\dagger z_j)=\mathrm{tr}(T_i^\dagger T_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and the $T_i$ matrices (which are $t\times t$) are rank-2. How can I do this? If so, can I make sure I use the least number of terms?

I would be happy even if I could only extract from $G$ the first element of such a decomposition.